# EclipseLink - Add Days in Date Using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using eclipselink 2.1 and I would like to get a little help in CriteriaBuilder,

How can I do this SQL ruler in Criteria API ?

```
AND TRUNC (  e008.atdt_008dtinclusao + e008.atni_008nro_dias_visual ) >= TRUNC (SYSDATE)
```

The first field is a Date, in my entity is a ***Joda DateTime***

The Second field is a ***Integer*** is a number of date to view.

I can not sum and truncate this part with the Criteria.
Thank you for the attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

Using **org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionBuilder** I could do:

```
    ExpressionBuilder officeExpression = new ExpressionBuilder(OfficeEntity.class);
    officeExpression.anyOf(OfficeFields.judicialNotifications);
    officeExpression.anyOf(OfficeFields.eventsHistoric);
    officeExpression.anyOf(OfficeFields.contracts);

    .and(ExpressionMath.add(officeExpression.get(OfficeFields.judicialNotifications).get(JudicialNotificationFields.dateInsert).toDate()
            , officeExpression.get(OfficeFields.judicialNotifications).get(JudicialNotificationFields.daysViewer)).equal(JodaTimeHelper.now().toDate()))
```